Human Drug Data Dictionary is incomplete
The data dictionary for human drug at https://open.fda.gov/data/datadictionary lists the fields and definitions, however for coded fields the value and meaning of the codes is not given. For example,
reporttype definition is "Code indicating the circumstances under which the report was generated" but what are the codes and what do the codes mean?
